# how to upload file saved in memory by multer to another API

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, multer

I have **2 separate NodeJS APIs** that uses [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) to save a file in **memory**.

My express middleware looks like this

```
import multer from 'multer';
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();

export default multer({ storage }).single('image');
```

I am able to receive the file which is saved in memory successfully so my **req.file.image** looks like this

```
{ 
  fieldname: 'image',
  originalname: 'image-2017-08-28-13-47-31-218.png',
  encoding: '7bit',   mimetype: 'image/png',
  buffer: <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0 ... >, 
  size: 493181
}
```

After receiving the file, on the **first** API, I need to send it to the **second API** that also uses **multer** & **express**

```
function secondApiReceiveImage(req, res) {
  console.log(req.file)
  console.log(req.files)
  console.log(req.body)
  res.send('ok');
}
```

I tried sending using the following implementations

Via https://github.com/request/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads

```
import request from 'request';

function firstApiReceiveImage(req, res) {
  const options = {
    url:'http://SECOND_API/api/image',
    formData: { image: req.file.buffer }
  };
  request.post(options, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
    console.log('err', err);
    console.log('body', body);
  });
}
```

In this case, logs of **req.file**, **req.files** and **req.body** are all ***undefined*** on **secondApiReceiveImage** API handler function

My next try was with https://github.com/form-data/form-data

```
import multer from 'multer';
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();

export default multer({ storage }).single('image');

function firstApiReceiveImage(req, res) {
  const CRLF = '\r\n';
  const form = new FormData();
  const opts = {
    header: `${CRLF} + '--' + ${form.getBoundary()} + ${CRLF} + 'X-Custom-Header: 123' + ${CRLF} + ${CRLF}`,
    knownLength: 1
  };

  form.append('image', req.file.image.buffer, opts);
  form.submit('http://SECOND_API/api/image', (err, res) => {
    console.log('err', err);
    console.log('res', res);
  });
}
```

I got the same result, **undefined** for **req.file**, **req.files** & **req.body** on the second API

These are my middlewares for both APIs aside from multer BTW

```
app.use(compression());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

I could have had an easier life if I can persist the file on the **first API**, but we are not allowed to save to disk in this case :(

Any advice for me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The team was able to get through this by converting the buffer to Stream first and send form data differently.

```
import stream from 'stream';
import rq from 'request-promise';

const { Duplex } = stream;

function bufferToStream(buffer) {
  const duplexStream = new Duplex();
  duplexStream.push(buffer);
  duplexStream.push(null);
  return duplexStream;
}

async function store({
  originalname, mimetype, size, buffer,
}) {
  logger.debug(`Saving image name:${originalname} type:${mimetype} size:${size}`);

  const formData = {
    image: {
      value: bufferToStream(buffer),
      options: {
        filename: originalname,
        contentType: mimetype,
        knownLength: size,
      },
    },
  };

  const options = Object.assign({}, IMAGE_SAVE_ENDPOINT, { formData });
  const response = await rq(options);
  return response.id;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I've stumbled upon the same issue and here is what I've managed to come up with.

First of all I used the form-data package to mimic the FormData data structure on the server side and here is the util file that does that.

```
    const FormData = require('form-data')
    const formData = new FormData()
    const config = {
       headers: {
         'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData.getBoundary()}`
       }
    }
    export default { data: formData, config }
```

and here is my node.js api file

```
import formSet from '../utils/formData'

const multer = require('multer')
const upload = multer()

const { Router } = require('express')
const router = Router()

......

router.post('/api/images', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
  formSet.data.append('image', req.file.buffer, { filename: req.file.originalname })
  formSet.data.append('other_data', 'value')
  const response = await axios.post('/images', formSet.data, formSet.config)

  .......

})
```

Comment: I was trying something similar to this, but it was missing the third argument to set the filename. Thanks!
I used this to upload a picture to my backend and from there, upload it to the Facebook Graph API. Without the filename it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Using **Request**, `formdata` should be set to the **buffer**:

```
formData: { image: req.file.buffer }
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! As you can see on my example above, I already tried this approach and it didn't work. The second API does not seem to detect the file sent as buffer. Not sure why :(

Comment: ah, you're right, there is a typo here. It's sort of a sudo code BTW, since I actually do pass 2 images to the 2nd API. I checked the code again to confirm that I do pass the buffer, not image. Have you tried ti simulate this code in a real API?

Comment: I checked all possible typos again using request & option formData. Still no luck :(

Comment: pass one image a time. I tested it works. So rest assured.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the way to upload files with multer through buffer and not storing locally...
Here is my code....

```
     var multer = require('multer');
     var storage= multer.memoryStorage();
     var upload = multer({storage: storage});
     var cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
     cloudinary.config({ 
       cloud_name: 'your-cloud-name', 
       api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY, //your api-key
       api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET //your api-secret
    });
```

Configure your cloudinary and multer as above.....

Get the buffer from req as follows..

```
 router.post("/",upload.single('image'),function(req,res){
   var buf = req.file.buffer.toString('base64');
   // Upload code Here
 )};
```

Upload code:

```
     cloudinary.uploader.upload("data:image/png;base64," + buf, function(result) {
          //your code here
          console.log(result);
        },{
          folder: 'folder-name' //if you want to store in a folder
        });
```

The output of result would be as follows:

```
      {
      asset_id: 'ed58484fb2bdce823f1b27d*******8',
      public_id: '**************',
      version: 1594455479,
      version_id: '68450****88842ce0aa319603e68d3',
      signature: '3785dbfc3**********883720b',
      width: 750,
      height: 500,
      format: 'png',
      resource_type: 'image',
      created_at: '2020-07-11T08:17:59Z',
      tags: [],
      pages: 1,
      bytes: 70846,
      type: 'upload',
      etag: 'd04dd691de532e941faccda846ef3d76',
      placeholder: false,
      url: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/*****************',
      secure_url: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/*******************'
    }
```