# Fetching image from URL and uploading to another via POST in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, post

In the following snippet, I'm using [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) and [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) to first retrieve an image file from a remote URL and then upload it to an S3 bucket (using [aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk) and [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) in a different script):

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import fs from 'fs';
import FormData from 'form-data';

const form = new FormData();

const processProfileImg = (imageURL, userID) => {
  fetch(imageURL, userID)
    .then((response) => {
      const dest = fs.createWriteStream(`./temp/${userID}.jpg`);
      response.body.pipe(dest);
    })
    .then((dest) => {
      form.append('profileImage', fs.createReadStream(`./temp/${userID}.jpg`));
      fetch(`https://www.schandillia.com/upload/profile-image?userID=${userID}`, { method: 'POST', body: form })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json));
    });
};

export default processProfileImg;
```

Problem is, this involves an intermediate step of first storing the file locally upon retrieval, before it's picked up for POST by the `form-data` function. Is there any way to bypass this step entirely? I don't want to save the file locally, I just want to pull it from the remote URL and POST it to the upload route without creating a local file.

**Update**: After slightly modifying the snippet to implement suggestions from Fransebas (first answer) and avoid async issues, I'm running into a new problem: The image being saved locally is alright, but the copy being uploaded to S3 is partially cut off!

**Additional code**: The route that handles POST upload, https://www.schandillia.com/upload/profile-image, is as follows and it works well when I try uploading the file using Postman.

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import express from 'express';
import aws from 'aws-sdk';
import multerS3 from 'multer-s3';
import multer from 'multer';
import path from 'path';

dotenv.config();
const router = express.Router();

// Set up S3
const s3 = new aws.S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.IAM_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.IAM_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
});

const checkFileType = (file, cb) => {
  // Allowed ext
  const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg/;
  // Check ext
  const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
  // Check mime
  const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
  if (mimetype && extname) {
    return cb(null, true);
  }
  return cb('Error: JPEG Only!');
};

// Single Upload
const profileImgUpload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3,
    contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
    bucket: `${process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME}/w`,
    acl: 'public-read',
    key(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, req.query.userID + path.extname(file.originalname));
    },
  }),
  limits: { fileSize: 2000000 }, // In bytes: 2000000 bytes = 2 MB
  fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
    checkFileType(file, cb);
  },
}).single('profileImage');

router.post('/profile-image', (req, res) => {
  profileImgUpload(req, res, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log('errors', error);
      res.json({ error });
    } else if (req.file === undefined) {
      // If File not found
      console.log('Error: No File Selected!');
      res.json('Error: No File Selected');
    } else {
      // If Success
      const imageName = req.file.key;
      const imageLocation = req.file.location;
      // Save the file name into database into profile model
      res.json({
        image: imageName,
        location: imageLocation,
      });
    }
  });
});
// End of single profile upload

// We export the router so that the server.js file can pick it up
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: It will have to be stored locally one way or another. You can store it in memory to eliminate the file IO, but that's about it. [This question talks about using multer to do something seemingly similar to what you're doing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46975590/215552).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used that specific way of sending data (I prefer ajax) but by looking at your example I suppose you can skip saving the image locally. If you see  `fs.createReadStream` creates a read stream. Look for ways of creating a read stream from what you got.

Also, I think you should put your sending code inside the `then` so you don't have async problems. For example, if your code for sending data is inside the `then` then you could use `response.body` to create the stream.

You almost got it, but you are still using the file, I think you can archive it with something more like this

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import fs from 'fs';
import FormData from 'form-data';

const form = new FormData();

const processProfileImg = (imageURL, userID) => {
  fetch(imageURL, userID)
    .then((response) => {
      // Use response.body directly, it contains the image right?
      form.append('profileImage', response.body);
      fetch(`https://www.schandillia.com/upload/profile-image?userID=${userID}`, { method: 'POST', body: form })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json));
    });
};

export default processProfileImg;
```

If I understand the documentation of `fetch` correctly `response.body` is already a stream.

Comment: Please see my update. I wrapped the upload code into a `.then()` as you suggested. But now the image being uploaded to S3 is partially cut off.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't find anything that does what the `fileSteamFromBody` placeholder is meant to do. At this point, I don't mind having to save a copy of the file locally so long as the upload goes through without hiccups. Am struggling with even this much.

Comment: If I understand this documentation correctly https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams the body is already a readableStream, take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const FormData = require('form-data');

//Get image
let imageResponse = await axios({
    url: imageUrl,
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
})

//Create form data
const form = new FormData()
form.append('image', imageResponse.data, {
    contentType: 'image/jpeg',
    name: 'image',
    filename: 'imageFileName.jpg'
})

//Submit form
let result = await axios({
    url: serverUrl, 
    method: "POST",
    data: form, 
    headers: { "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form._boundary}` }
})
```